# Ubuntu Sofware Centre does not download packages when connected to Cisco VPN

Tags: software-center, synaptic, cisco

I am not able to download packages through Ubuntu Software Centre when connected to Cisco VPN. However, I am able to do the same from Synaptic by adding proxy settings.

How do I make Ubuntu Software Centre to make use of the same settings as Synaptic package manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer. just add the proxy settings to /etc/apt/apt.conf. This solution works for both cli and the software centre.